# Writing all powers of 2 not exceeding given number

Tags: c++

here is the code.

```
int n,power=2;
cin>>n;
cout<<power<<endl;
while(power<n){
power=power*2;
cout<<power<<endl;
}
```

For example, if i wrote 20, the output should be "2 4 8 16". Instead, it writes me "2 4 8 16 32" What should i change in this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the ordering, you increase the value after checking:

```
while(power<n){
cout<<power<<endl;
power=power*2;
}
```

You probably want to remove the first `cout` as well to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of the `for` loop:

```
for (int power = 1; power < n; power = power * 2) {
    cout << power << endl;
}
```

Comment: Plus one for the first idiomatic C++ solution. Although `power *= 2` in the loop might be even better. (And power should start at  2, not 1)

Answer (score 1):

You perform the test before you increase the value and print it! Therefore even the first value which exceeds your limit gets printed. Simply rewrite it this way:

```
int n, power = 2;
cin >> n;
while(power < n) {
    cout << power << endl;
    power *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the condition to

```
while (power*2 < n)
```

Or print before you modify the value

```
cout << power << endl;
power *= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

*An alternative suggestion*

We can pre-compute the powers of 2, until a defined limit (say 2^30) and then parse the vector again, to print elements not exceeding the given number

```
// get the Limit from the user
int limit; 
cin >> limit;

std::vector<int> P; 
for(int i=1; i<30; i++)
   P.push_back((1 << i));

for(auto c: P)
    if(c < limit)
      std::cout << c << " "; 
std::cout << std::endl;
```